# [URL rewriting Apache]port redirect and keep URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, port

I need to do a port redirection on my server while retaining the original visible URL.

For example http://localhost/Jupiter/ redirect to http://localhost:8080/ while retaining http://localhost/Jupiter/

Now i have this configuration but url retain don't work :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^(.*)/Jupiter/ http://%{SERVER_NAME}:8080/ [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried with flag [R=301,L] but it don't work too

On first configuration I haved :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyRequests On
ProxyPass /Jupiter/ http://%{SERVER_NAME}:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /Jupiter/ http://%{SERVER_NAME}:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

But this make a 404 for pictures and css

I'm interested of all solutions.

Comment: if pictures and css is problem add this before the rule to ensure existing files and directories are served as is: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

Comment: Pictures and css are load when i use the rewriteEngine , but not with the ProxyRequests